# Testing fields which are going to be initialized by field injection (CDI)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

let's assume we've got the following snippet as part of an full Java EE application:

```
@Singleton
public class LoginService {


  @Inject
  private UserDAO userDAO;



  protected boolean login(String username, String password){

   // [...]
   User user = userDAO.findByUsername(username);

  // [...]

  }


}
```

UserDAO is an interface and there's one specific class implementation of that interface called DatabaseUserDAO which is injected into the userDAO field.

Now I am going to write a test for the login method e. g. `testLoginSuccessfulIfLoginDataCorrect()`. But as I don't want to depend on the database I just want to stub it by using a class e.g. `public class TestUserDAO implements UserDAO`and inject this one instead of the default class which whould be injected. What are the possibilities to implement it? Let's also assume that there is no constructor injection or other ways to initialize the field.

Comment: I think the most CDI-oriented way is to use an [**Alternative** bean](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#alternatives). An alternative, if enabled, will take the place of the original bean and any injection will be done using this alternative. Have you considered that? I can elaborate further, just not sure that's what you are after.

Comment: Also take a look at [CDI Unit](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/).

Answer (score 2):

Use arquillian (http://arquillian.org/) along with mockito (http://site.mockito.org/) or one of its derivates to:

- create a mockup of UserDAO to inject
- create a bundle from your class under test along with the mock
- create a junit test which gets your LoginService along with the mock injected and can use it for tests:

Example (modified from actual code to somewhat match your class names):
(Attention: this kind of deployment generation only works for maven projects)

```
 @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
 public class LoginSeviceTest {
     // a pattern I find quite neat: hold the mocks in a static local class, but they might be anywhere else
     public static class LocalMocks {
         @Produces public static UserDAO mockUser = Mockito.mock(UserDAO.class);
     }

     @Deployment
     public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
         PomEquippedResolveStage pom = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");
         BeansDescriptor beansXml = Descriptors.create(BeansDescriptor.class)
             .addDefaultNamespaces().getOrCreateAlternatives()
             .up();

         WebArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
             .addAsLibraries(pom.resolve("org.mockito:mockito-core").withTransitivity().asFile())
             .addClass(LoginService.class)  // eventually further classes or packages you depend on
             .addClass(LoginSeviceTest.LocalMocks.class)
             .addAsWebInfResource(new StringAsset(beansXml.exportAsString()), "beans.xml");

         return jar;
     }

     @Inject LoginService loginService;

     @Test
     public void testLogin() {
         // use the injected loginService here for actual tests
     }
 }
```

Note, that you do *not* need to change the class under test this way to make testing possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are not secret for that.

You have four possibilities.

1. Create a constructor for all DAOs (EJBs).

   ```
   @Singleton
   public class LoginService {

     @Inject
     private UserDAO userDAO;

     LoginService (UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
     }

   }
   ```
2. Create a set for each DAO.

   ```
   @Singleton
   public class LoginService {

     @Inject
     private UserDAO userDAO;

     setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Set the variable directly with default access

   ```
   @Singleton
   public class LoginService {

     @Inject
     UserDAO userDAO;

   }
   ```

   And in your test:

   ```
   loginService.userDAO = userDAOMocked.
   ```

So, you can mock the UserDAO and pass to the LoginService test as parameter using the constructor or by setter.

Another one is [by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805504/2387977) (without constructor or setter), but I dislike this approach...:

4. Reflection

   ```
   public static void setPrivateField(Class<? extends Object> instanceFieldClass, Object instance, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) throws Exception {
       Field setId = instanceFieldClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
       setId.setAccessible(true);
       setId.set(instance, fieldValue);
   }
   ```

   And to use:

   ```
   setPrivateField(loginService, "userDAO", userDAOMocked);
   ```

Comment: Using something like arquilian is more modern in my opinion. No need to add all this code to the classes just for testing

Comment: @Kukeltje, Arquillian is a good solution too, but starts an application server to work (less performance) and introduces a new dependency in the project. Not all the solutions above introduce new code and some of them make the test more simple than using Arquillian (your example illustrate that). I don't think I deserve a down vote for four viable solutions, but it's ok.

Comment: 1 2 and 3 all expose fields/constructors in a way that they should not be used in the real application but that **can** be done. It is code only needed for testing but usable in 'production' (I've seen it being (ab)used). And regarding the 'container' being started, well, the less performance could also be seen as more realistic performance. For simple cases 1 2 and 3 work, but if you not only want to do unit testing but also integration testing, things get more complex. Injection here, something there... But you are right, downvote is not good... removed! Cheers

Comment: removed downvote (But I do think the other answer should have more upvotes ;-))